# Mathpix - where to put the JSON

Tags: http, request, header

So I'm trying to use the Mathpix OCR API. Their instructions are here: https://docs.mathpix.com/?javascript#authorization  There are three tabs on top right side: JSON, curl, python. I'm working on javascript, so I imagine I should use the json but what is the curl?

But my main question is, where on my code should I put the request headers and then the body parameters? They say that request headers should look like:

```
{
"content-type": "application/json",
"app_id": "YOUR_APP_ID",
"app_key": "YOUR_APP_KEY"
}
```

Then I should Post:
`POST https://api.mathpix.com/v3/text`

And send an image should be done this way:

```
{
  "src": "data:image/jpeg;base64,..."
  "formats": ["text", "data", "html"]
  "data_options": {
      "include_asciimath": true,
      "include_latex": true
  }
}
```

Where exactly does this code go?? In the js file, I imagine, not the html, correct? But where and how? So if I had the following barebones boilerplate running a local server, where does the mathpix go here:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

  app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
  });

  app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("server is running on port 3000.");
  });
```

Sorry, that I'm such a newbie but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The mathpix api can use JSON to send the data. So in your javascript code you can use the `fetch` api to make a request to the server. So as an example you would do:

```
//Consants to fill
const appId = "YOUR API KEY";
const appKey = "APP KEY";
var url = "Math PIX url";

//Importing fetch
const fetch = require("fetch")

//Making the image
const image = {
  "src": "data:image/jpeg;base64,..."
  "formats": ["text", "data", "html"]
  "data_options": {
      "include_asciimath": true,
      "include_latex": true
  }
}

//Send the request to the server
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  body:JSON.stringify({
    "src": "data:image/jpeg;base64,..."
    "formats": ["text", "data", "html"]
    "data_options": {
        "include_asciimath": true,
        "include_latex": true
    }
  }),
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "app_id": appId,
    "app_key": appKey
  }
});

console.log(response)
```

I would suggest you read up on :
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-and-post-method-using-fetch-api/#:~:text=Fetch%20also%20supports%20the%20POST,post%20content%20with%20an%20ID](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-and-post-method-using-fetch-api/#:%7E:text=Fetch%20also%20supports%20the%20POST,post%20content%20with%20an%20ID).

Comment: Thank you. But it tells me SyntaxError. await is only valid in async function. If I take away the await, it doesn't recognize fetch, even after I npm installed it. Wt ???

Comment: You might need to require('fetch') and wrap the whole thing inside a async function

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how would I do that specifically? How would the entire code look? Thanks.

Comment: Another thing I realized is that fetch is only supposed to be used on the client side. So I did that within an html doc. But then I get the message: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1". And I don't get the equation back.

Comment: in a html doc you can use the ```script``` tags to use fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch returns a promise that you need to use .then() to process. Here is the code.

```
//Consants to fill
const appId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const appKey = "1234556788990";
var url = "https://api.mathpix.com/v3/latex";

//Importing fetch
const fetch = require("node-fetch")


var _data = {

                "src": "https://mathpix.com/examples/limit.jpg",
                "formats": "text",
                "data_options": {
                    "include_asciimath": true,
                    "include_latex": true
                }
            }

var _header = {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "app_id": appId,
                "app_key": appKey
            }

//Send the request to the server
const response = fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  body:JSON.stringify(_data),
  headers: _header
})
.then(response => response.json()) 
.then(json => console.log(json));;
```